# Path of the express

Tags: node.js, express

Why express command not found. Here is the path for express.

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/express
```

When I install the express, the terminal shows the path. I used

```
npm install -g express-generator  
npm install -g express
```

But when I run express, it doesn't work. In this directory, express is globally right? But why can't be found. I don't understand the logic.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install express locally, rather than globally.

http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation

> In general, the rule of thumb is:
>
> 1. If you’re installing something that you want to use in your program, using require('whatever'), then install it locally, at the root of your project.
> 2. If you’re installing something that you want to use in your shell, on the command line or something, install it globally, so that its binaries end up in your PATH environment variable.

Based on this, you want to install `express-generator` using the `-g` flag as you will use it as a command line tool, but you want to install `express` without this flag as it's a module you will want to `require()` it in your application.

---

Take a look at the installation guide:

http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html

It says to install the `express-generator` module as a global module as you will use it as a command line utility to scaffold your new applications.

Once you have scaffolded an application using the `express myapp` command, you just have to run `npm install` in the `myapp` directory which will download the rest of the dependencies to your projects local `./node_modules` directory. It does this by reading the contents of the generated `package.json` file.

---

Lesson to take away: Don't install with the `-g` flag unless the modules instruction guide explicitly says to do so.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand the difference between " /usr/lib/node_modules" and " /usr/local/lib/node_modules", why I use command "npm install -g express" it install in the first path, but I am in my own directory, say "/home/czhu/". Can you explain to me?

Comment: You should be installing all modules in the 'root' of your project unless the module is built to be a global module. If you drop the ```-g``` flag from ```npm install express``` it will install in your current directory rather than ```/user/lib/node_modules```.